# Проблема с отображением во вкладке проекта intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне убрать отображение полей во фрейме проекта?

Нашел решение - убрать галочку с пункта Show Members)))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение - убрать галочку с пункта Show Members)))[image: введите сюда описание изображения]